# Why InputStreamResource has `isOpen()` which return always true?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring core library class `InputStreamResource` has `isOpen()` and `exists(`) method, which always return true.

Why it is there? Is there any reason and where it can be used?

Code reference:

```
public class InputStreamResource extends AbstractResource {
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final String description;
    private boolean read;

    public InputStreamResource(InputStream inputStream) {
        this(inputStream, "resource loaded through InputStream");
    }

    public InputStreamResource(InputStream inputStream, @Nullable String description) {
        this.read = false;
        Assert.notNull(inputStream, "InputStream must not be null");
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.description = description != null ? description : "";
    }

    public boolean exists() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isOpen() {
        return true;
    }
...
...
}
```

Comment: Those methods are inherited from `Resource` (via `AbstractResource`). Other implementations might return something else. Whoever designed this class defined instances of it as always existing and always being open.

Comment: Conversely, `AbstractResource#isOpen` always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Resource#isOpen](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html#isOpen()), then it clarifies (emphasis mine):

> Indicate whether this resource represents a handle with an open stream. **If true, the InputStream cannot be read multiple times, and must be read and closed to avoid resource leaks.**
>
> Will be false for typical resource descriptors.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html#isOpen()

Comment: @fantaghirocco the question is _why_ `InputStreamResource#isOpen` always returns true, that's presupposed information.